# What's the relationship between .gitignore and Dialog of Configure Ignored Files in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, gitignore

I ususally added rules in .gitignore.But today I find there is a Dialog to ignore file.

Do I need to use Dialog of Configure Ignored Files if I put all rule in .gitignore?Or is it better to use the dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use `.gitignore`. The dialog to configure ignored files is specific to IntelliJ IDEA/Android Studio, while `.gitignore` will also be understood by the Git command line client and other tools that work with Git.

There is no need to duplicate the .gitignore rules in the Android Studio dialog.